# Run python script against Apple's stock python from Cocoa app

Tags: python, swift, cocoa

I am trying to run a 'hello world' python script from a button in a Cocoa app just to test. Here's my code:

```
    @IBAction func test(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Running process")
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/python"
    task.arguments = ["/Users/justMe/Desktop/test/test.py"]
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    print ("All Done!")
}
```

Unfortunately, what I get is the following:
    Running process
/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/Users/justMe/Desktop/test/test.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
All Done!

The file has been chmod to 777 and I am at a loss as to why this won't work with the stock Python that Apple provides in Mojave. Any ideas on a workaround?

Comment: The file might be chmod 777, but what about the containing directories? And how is the parent script being ran? Is it in a restricted execution environment, like Mac apps usually are now?

Comment: I added a /testing/ directory, sudo chmod 777 it, added the python file, chmod again, adjusted the script, got the same result unfortunately.

Comment: How are you running the script? From Bash? Like, `python path-to-script.py`?

Comment: running /usr/bin/python /testing/test.py from terminal works fine. I am attempting to run the script from the above IBAction in my Cocoa app, which consists of a single button wired up to that function.

Comment: I see. It's not really a Python issue at all then. Most likely, you're running into the MacOS sandbox: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html -- I have no idea how that works, but I believe you have to ask for granular permissions and have the user "grant" them.

Comment: Nothing there seemed to help unfortunately

Comment: Is your app Sandboxed? If so, this is probably why you encounter this issue; you'll need to setup **entitlements**.

Comment: Does it work if you switch off App Sandbox?

Comment: Yep! That was the problem. I am primarily an iOS developer and didn't know about the default sandboxing on MacOS that has been recently enforced like it is on iOS. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I can't add a comment yet. What happens when you try to

```
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/python -c \"print('hi')\""
```

and remove the task.arguments line

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work as it yields the following: test[2045:43223] [General] launch path not accessible